# Sticky Navbar Magento2

Tags: magento2, css, jquery, sticky-menu, scroll

I want to make the navigation bar to be sticky.

I have completed that in the below way.

Now I want to make the logo to display in the navbar when we scroll.

I don't know how to add the logo to the navbar via jquery. I tried this way but I am getting the logo getting cloned many times in the navbar.

suggest me how to add the logo to the navbar via jquery.

```
            define([
            'jquery' 
            ],
            function($){  
            'use strict';
            $(window).scroll(function(){
            var $window = $(window);
            var windowsize = $window.width();
            var height = $(document).scrollTop();
            if(height > 180 ) {
                $(".logo").clone().appendTo(".nav-sections");
                $('.nav-sections').addClass('sticky');
            $('.page-header').addClass('sticky-header'); 
            }else{
                $('.nav-sections').removeClass('sticky');
                $('.page-header').removeClass('sticky-header'); 
            }
            });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require([
        'jquery'
], function ($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
          var sticky = $('header.page-header'),
              stickyMenu = $('nav.navigation'),
              scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

          if (scroll >= 180){
            sticky.addClass('fixed'); 
            stickyMenu.addClass('fixed-nav-navigation');    
          }
          else{
            sticky.removeClass('fixed');
            stickyMenu.removeClass('fixed-nav-navigation');
          } 
        });
    });
});
```

css

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 8;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: smoothScroll 1s forwards;
}
.fixed-nav-navigation {
 position: fixed;
 width: your choice
 margin-top: your choice
 z-index: 8;
 top: your choice
 margin-left: your choice
 animation: smoothScroll 1s forwards;
}
```